# Why does the hash change of a folder unzipped even when the contents do not change?

Tags: c#, md5, sha1

I have an application that hashes a directory and then zips/compresses it. When unzipping the directory, not making any changes to either folder, or when unzipping the directory twice in 2 different locations the hashes do not match. I am using SHA1. Is there a way for the hashes to stay the same? Is MD5 capable of this?

For example: MyZipped.zip.  If i take and unzip this archive twice, using 7zip/winRar/WinZip and then hash them, all of the contents came from the same zip and should be exactly the same. But they all come up with different hashes.

```
try
            {
                var path = ProcessingFolder + @"\" + inputName;
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                     .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();

                SHA1 md5 = SHA1.Create();

                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    string file = files[i];

                    // hash path
                    string relativePath = file.Substring(path.Length + 1);
                    byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
                    md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

                    // hash contents
                    byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                    if (i == files.Count - 1)
                        md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
                    else
                        md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
                }

                hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```